# javascript error. Array into loop for

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have a problem with this for loop

```
var barClass= document.getElementsByClassName("br");
    for(var i=0;i<barClass.length;i++){
        barClass[i].addEventListener('mousedown',function() {initMagic(this.event,i);},false);
        barClass[i].addEventListener('mouseup',function() {endMagic(this.event,i);},false);
        barClass[i].addEventListener('mousemove',function() {mouMove(this.event,i);},false);
}
function initMagic(e,n){
    alert(n);
}
```

Because the result of `alert(n)` is identical to `barClass.length` any `barClass[i]` I will get same result?

Comment: In short - `function() {initMagic(this.event,i)}` creates a closure over variable `i`, not the current value of `i`. Wrap the contents of your loop in `(function(i) { ... })(i)`.

Comment: Please let me to see. I do not understand you.

Comment: `for(var i=0;i<barClass.length;i++){ (function(i) { barClass[i].addEventListener('mousedown',function() {initMagic(this.event,i);},false); barClass[i].addEventListener('mouseup',function() {endMagic(this.event,i);},false); barClass[i].addEventListener('mousemove',function() {mouMove(this.event,i);},false); })(i); }`

Comment: I've tried so. But event passes as undefine.

Comment: Ah, right, sorry. `this` will change. So capture it with `var that = this;` at the top, and change `this.event` into `that.event`. Or don't even bother with `this.event` - all handlers will receive the event as their parameter, so you can write `function(evt) { initMagic(evt, i); }` (and so forth).

Comment: very thanks...now go!! could you explain what this means'(function(){})(i)'

Comment: Unfortunately, `this` is a pretty important concept in JavaScript, you should read it [in more depth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) than a comment on Stack Overflow. If you meant some other "this", you need to be more precise (and also read the answer that was linked as duplicate).

Comment: no.I wanted to know why the function you have insert into round parenthesis and why next you are insert i in round parenthesis

Comment: Already explained in the duplicate question and its answer. Which is precisely the reason why it is marked as duplicate.